# Subtracting Current year Rank from Previous Year RANK in Qlik Sense

Tags: visualization, qliksense, qlik-expression

I want to show (current year rank - Previous year rank) in a dynamic way. That means if new data is loaded its automatically calculates the rank and displays.

```
Company                 RANK          Financial_Year
    A                    21             2021 
    A                    22             2022
    B                    46             2021
    B                    56             2021
    C                    78             2021
    C                    36             2022
```

```
Company                 RANK          
    A                    1                         
    B                    10           
    C                   -42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to hard-code your fiscal years, you can use the following expression as a Measure in your table:

```
Only({<Financial_Year={'2022'}>} RANK)
-
Only({<Financial_Year={'2021'}>} RANK)
```

If you need for it to dynamically compare the most recent fiscal year to the previous fiscal year, you can do something like this:

```
Only({<Financial_Year={'$(=Max(all Financial_Year))'}>} RANK)
-
Only({<Financial_Year={'$(=Max(all Financial_Year) - 1)'}>} RANK)
```

This set expression works by using [Dollar-sign expansion of numbers](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-modifiers-dollar-sign-expansions.htm#anchor-2) by using the `$(=...)` syntax.

Comment: Is 'all' Mandatory there ?

Comment: `All` is only mandatory if you want the expression to use the most recent fiscal year relative to the **entire data set** as opposed to seeing the most recent fiscal year only relative to the **current selections**. You can see more information about the `All` qualifier on [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/define-aggregation-scope.htm).

Comment: Like if you select a **[Date]** of 2018-04-18 and the set expression uses the `All` qualifier (`=Max(all Financial_Year)`), it will still return 2022. However, if you select 2018-04-18 but you *don't* use the `All` qualifier (`=Max(Financial_Year)`), it will instead return 2018.

Comment: Thank you so much Brane for such a detailed explanation. Much appreciated :) Thank for helping out.

Comment: Happy to help! Make sure to mark the answer as being “correct” to help others find it in the future :)